# how to make a segue to a UIview Controller through a tableview cell of another UIview Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I added a tableview and tableview cell in my view controller and I want to make a segue to another view controller through that tableview cell I have, is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

1. Ctrl click that UITableViewCell and point it to the other view controller
2. Choose a segue type you wanna apply in the popup menu.

Comment: You'll have to expand on "it's not working". IB isn't letting you do that? It doesn't work at runtime? Give as much detail as you can.

Comment: So I add a tableview and and tableview cell to a view controller, but didn't attach it with header file. I added one more View controller to the storyBoard and then ctrl drag the tableview cell to the new view controller to make a segue but its not working for me.

Comment: And Yes its not just letting me drag and perform a segue to other View Controller.